# Soundcloud SDK 3. Non stop stream of favourite (liked) songs

Tags: javascript, jquery, soundcloud

How can I stream all favourite songs continuously, without a stop?

I wrote a js code that gets my favourites songs, streams a random one. Streams a next random song when the first song is finished. But my goal is to stream all songs one by one, forever, until I want to stop it manually.

My code:

```
var getRandom = function(min, max){
    return Math.round(Math.random() * (max - min) + min);
}

function playFon() {
    SC.connect().then(function(){
    SC.get('/me').then(function(me) { 
        SC.get('/users/'+ me.id +'/favorites?limit=200').then(function(data) { 
                var num_of_res = data.length;
                var sid = getRandom(0, num_of_res);
                var song = '/tracks/' + data[sid].id;

                SC.stream(song).then(function(player){

                    player.on('play-start', function(){
                        console.log('Playing '+ sid + ' ' + song);  
                        console.log(data[sid]);
                    }).on('finish', function(){
                        sid = getRandom(0, num_of_res);
                        song = '/tracks/' + data[sid].id;

                        console.log('Playing '+ sid + ' ' + song);  
                        console.log(data[sid]);

                        SC.stream(song).then(function(player){
                            player.play();
                        });
                    });

                    player.play();

                });
        });
        });
    }).then(function(data){
      console.log('You are playing now.');
    }).catch(function(error){
      console.log('Error: ' + error.message);
    });

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a solution. I used SoundManager2 and a recursive function nextTrack() to play next random track. I think it could be done via SoundCloud player too.

```
var fav_songs_arr = [];
var num_of_res = 0;
var sid = 0;
var url = '';

var getRandom = function(min, max){
    return Math.round(Math.random() * (max - min) + min);
}

var nextTrack = function(){
    soundManager.stopAll();
    sid = getRandom(0, num_of_res);
    url = fav_songs_arr[sid].stream_url + '?consumer_key=' + app_id;
    var mySound = soundManager.createSound({
        url: url,
        onfinish: function(){
            nextTrack();
        }
    });
    mySound.play();
}

function playFon() {
    SC.connect().then(function(){
      SC.get('/me').then(function(me) { 
        SC.get('/users/'+ me.id +'/favorites?limit=200').then(function(data) { 
                fav_songs_arr = data;
                num_of_res = fav_songs_arr.length;
                nextTrack();
          });
        });
    }).then(function(data){
      console.log('You are playing now.');
    }).catch(function(error){
      console.log('Error: ' + error.message);
    });

}
```